# Changing Mac OS X User Password Programmatically or via Script

Tags: cocoa, macos, passwords

I need to be able to change a user's password from a cron task or from an ssh session.  Is there an easy way to do that with a bash script?  If not, what's the easiest way to do it in Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `passwd` shell command.

Comment: Doesn't passwd block redirecting input?  If it doesn't, you could do this but you'd have to write all three lines out to a file (original, new, new) and then redirect it, but I thought that wasn't supposed to work (for safety).  Could be wrong.

Comment: beware, passwd(1) does not change the password the the user's keychain!

Answer (score 2):

Apple introduced [CSIdentitySetPassword](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443568-csidentitysetpassword?language=objc) API in Mac OS 10.5 that allows to change password as follows:

```
#import <Collaboration/Collaboration.h>

    AuthorizationRef authRef = NULL; // You have to initialize authRef

    CBIdentityAuthority *authority = [CBIdentityAuthority defaultIdentityAuthority];
    CSIdentityRef identity = [CBIdentity identityWithName:user authority:authority].CSIdentity;
    if (CSIdentityGetClass(identity) == kCSIdentityClassUser) {
        CSIdentitySetPassword(identity, (__bridge CFStringRef)newPassword);
        CSIdentityCommit(identity, authRef, NULL);
    }
```

AuthenticationRef can be initialized like int [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34810104/4797324) response.